# Declaration of an array of strings and selecting a single character

Tags: c, arrays, string, declaration

I am new to c programming and am trying to print on the screen which key of a keypad is pressed. I have the program to the stage where it prints the row and column number of the key that was pressed. I was thinking if I could declare an array of strings containing all 16 key characters, the row and column numbers could index the array. Here is my feeble attempt at it.

```
 char key[4];
 strcpy(key[0], "CD.Z");
 strcpy(key[1], "89AB");
 strcpy(key[2], "4567");
 strcpy(key[3], "0123");
```

...

```
printf("The key pressed was %c", key[colnum][rownum]);
```

Comment: `char key[4];` ---> `char key[4][5];`

Comment: or `char *key[4] = {"CD.Z", "89AB", "4567", "0123"};`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That was the mistake. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) in a comment, your types are wrong.

Also, there's no point in using run-time `strcpy()` to copy characters around, you can just use compile-time initializers to set up a string array:

```
const char *keys[] = { "CD.Z", "89AB", "4567", "0123" };
```

The above declares `keys` to be an array of `char *`, which is C's "string type" (it actually only means "pointer to character", but it's commonly used for strings). No length is specified for the array, the compiler automatically computes it based on the initializer expression on the right hand side of the `=`.

So, indexing like this:

```
printf("keys[2] is '%s'\n", keys[2]);
```

will get you the 3rd element (C indexes arrays from 0).

Since pointers can be indexed as well, you can also do:

```
printf("second char of '%s' is '%c'\n", keys[2], keys[2][1]);
```

Here, `keys[2][1]` means "first get the 3rd element from the `keys` array, then get the 2nd element from that array". This treats a character pointer as an array (by using the `[]` indexing operator) but that is fine in C, all pointers can be treated as arrays like that.

Answer (score 2):

This code fragment should not compile.
You tried to copy a char array to a char.
The compiler should emit an error

Modify it to this version.

```
char key[4][5];
strcpy(key[0], "CD.Z");
strcpy(key[1], "89AB");
strcpy(key[2], "4567");
strcpy(key[3], "0123");
```

Answer (score 0):

define your character array like

```
char *keys[] = { "CD.Z", "89AB", "4567", "0123" };
```

after pressing key you may show row and column number as

```
c = getchar();
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
   for(j=0;j<4;j++)
   {
      if(keys[i][j]==c)
      {
           printf("Key of Row %d and Column %d was pressed",i+1,j+1);
      }
   }
}
```

this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
key[0]
```

means it can hold only one character, while you're holding four characters. For this, you need to declare like following :

```
char key[4][5]= {"CD.Z", "89AB", "4567", "0123"};
```